# How to use Extjs tool tips with title and text  when xtype is 'actioncolumn'

Tags: extjs, extjs4, tooltip, gridpanel

how to use Tool tip with both text and title when xtype is actioncolumn in Ext.grid.Panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can put html into tooltip. Example:

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    width: 50,
    items: [{
        icon   : '../shared/icons/fam/delete.gif',
        tooltip: '<h3>Title</h3>Text text text',
        handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {}
    }]
}
```